# Customisation for Android BottomView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar, android-bottomnavigationview

[![I want bottom bar like this][1]][1]

Using below library in android to customize bottom tab bar :
https://github.com/Droppers/AnimatedBottomBar

It is quite easy to use and provide many animation.
But, I don't want the menu text content to display in bottom bar.

I want only icons to display while it is selected or not selected.

How can I achieve with this library?
Or Is there any way to acheive such thing?

Comment: did you find answer to your question ? if not I can asnwer

Comment: @rajan.kali No I am still looking for it. Any help pls. much appriciated.

Comment: I have answered the question to solve your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the library mentioned, it does not support this feature currently, but we can tweak the code to make it work for your usecase, but to do that you need to include the code as a module/folder instead instead of dependency.

To achieve that, you need to follow below steps

- You need to get rid of dependency of `implementation 'nl.joery.animatedbottombar:library:1.0.9'`
- Clean project to remove it from cache
- you can clone the code, add `'library'` folder from code as a Android module, then include it in your gradle using `implementation project(path: ':library')`

Once above steps are done, you can modify the code to your needs. Now for your use case, do replace `updateTabType` method present at `line#99` inside `library/src/main/java/nl/joery/animatedbottombar/TabView.kt` file to below

```
private fun updateTabType() {
    animatedView = icon_layout
    selectedAnimatedView = icon_layout //here we are forcing it use icon_layout for both views all the time
    if (selectedAnimatedView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        animatedView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        selectedAnimatedView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    } else {
        animatedView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        selectedAnimatedView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    bringViewsToFront()
}
```

> Also the library is licensed under MIT Open Source License, so you can
> happily change your own version of code free of cost.

**Update**

Also, in `library` modules gradle, please remove references to bintray, that is not required

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.9"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.61"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1"
}
```

Comment: In that case, you have to write all the animations and styles yourself.

Comment: Have updated the answer, ideally you can add bintray classpath in root project, but in your case it not needed, just replace library gradle with above content

Comment: Also hardcoded lib version and kotlin version instead of variables, paste the uodate gradle, it is working for me

Comment: did you imported `library` folder as android library? in that case library folder will have `build.gradle` file, just replace content with above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228797/discussion-between-rajan-kali-and-jaimin-modi).

Answer (score 0):

If you see in the description of the repo, you will see there are some attributes regarding the tab appearance

add this `app:abb_selectedTabType = "icon"` to the code that you might have already added in the xml like below

```
<nl.joery.animatedbottombar.AnimatedBottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:abb_selectedTabType="text"
        app:abb_indicatorAppearance="round"
        app:abb_indicatorMargin="16dp"
        app:abb_indicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:abb_tabs="@menu/tabs"
        app:abb_selectedTabType = "icon" 
        app:abb_selectedIndex="1" />
```

Comment: But Its for selected. I dont want text in case of not selected value also.